# Authenticate multiple WS Federation

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, active-directory

We currently have a multi-tenant backend that needs to authenticate requests coming from different SSO such as WSFederation.

Is there any recommended approach for multi-tenancy authentication? As the tenant list comes from an HTTP request, we need to validate request with a different configurations, since we do not want TenantA to be able to connect to TenantB using a different authority.

We are looking to create a microservice that will handle these multi realms of authentication per tenant and return a signed authorization JWT so the other microservice knows that the authentication was completedé

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a OAuthentication 2.0 server that has the capabilities to use multiple sources for your users, this will save you a lot of time, since you don't need to implement those interfaces in your app, only in your Authentication.

A good option for this would be keycloak, by default, it has a local user store, has identity providers for multiple social networks and LDAP. Best out of this is that you can create your own user federation, so, it can read users from MySQL or any other data-source that you might want to use.

Creating a "micro service" with all of this would require a lot of time and resources that you might not be willing to spend in just your user storage